# How do I fire client-side Grails validation manually via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, grails

I am just using basic Grails, with the default client-side validation that looks like this (not even sure what plugin it is):

[image]

Just looking for how I can test that manually?  In the past with jQuery validation I had done something like this:

```
if($('#myForm').valid()) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a library of any sort. That's just your browser supporting the "required" attribute of HTML5 forms. Grails doesn't include any client-side form validation library. Use a jQuery one of your choice.